# Putting data from a workbook (inside a textbox) to another workbook (at worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to connecting data with 2 Workbooks.

I've a workbook with some textboxes, which texts need to be reallocated to another workbook (master workbook) in a specific sheet.

I've tried to set a usual code routine, when I run the code to take the text inside a textbox to a empty row I'm having a compile error "Method or data member not found", even with declared workbook, worksheet and objects/textbox.

Below I show a piece of code.

Can anyone help me with this error?

```
Dim mestre As Workbook, Servo As Workbook
Dim cadastro As Worksheet, listacadastro As Worksheet, controle As     Worksheet, listamatricula As Worksheet
Dim boxnomecompleto1 As TextBox


varmestre = Worksheets("99. Controles").Range("C19").Value
varservo = Worksheets("99. Controles").Range("C20").Value
Set mestre = Workbooks.Open(varmestre)
Set Servo = Workbooks.Open(varservo)

'range C19 and C20 had the workbook location

Set cadastro = Servo.Worksheets("01. Cadastro")
Set listacadastro = mestre.Worksheets("01. Lista Cadastro")
Set controle = Servo.Worksheets("99. Controles")
Set listamatricula = mestre.Worksheets("02. Lista de Matriculados")


n = 2000

For i = 8 To n

If listacadastro.Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then

    listacadastro.Cells(i, 2).Value = "C" & ncadastro
    listacadastro.Cells(i, 4).Value = cadastro.boxnomecompleto1.Value

End if
Exit for
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: This one: "listacadastro.Cells(i, 4).Value = cadastro.boxnomecompleto1.Value"

Comment: `boxnomecompleto1` has not been set  in the code.

Comment: I can't find the properly method to set textbox

Comment: since in the error line `listacadastro` already worked in previous line. that  indicate problem in `cadastro.boxnomecompleto1.Value` part. again `cadastro` had already been set, that indicate problem with `boxnomecompleto1` part. if is the correct name of textbox then code  should run.   Check the name of textbox (it is assumed it is a Activex text box on sheet `cadastro`) . if that is the fact, then it is not needed to be `DIm  ...  as TextBox` in the declare section and also no need to set it again..

Comment: Another issue you used `ncadastro` it is not found in the code except line `listacadastro.Cells(i, 2).Value = "C" & ncadastro`. what it expected to be? Also you are using `Exit for`. is it typo instead of `Next` or you intended to use it in the `if` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I will assume that the code you posted is not complete. As it has already been noted in the comments section there are several issues like `ncadastro` not being declared or initialized and `For-Next` loop missing the `Next` part.

Also, please make sure you declare your `varmestre` and `varservo` variables and that you use a reference to a specific workbook when you assign values to them. For example:

```
dim varmestre as string
dim varservo as string
varmestre = thisWorkbook.Worksheets("99. Controles").Range("C19").Value 'Of course it doesn't have to be ThisWorkbook necessarily. It can be anything you want.
varservo = thisWorkbook.Worksheets("99. Controles").Range("C20").Value
```

Secondly, as far your text box is concerned:

**If it's a simple text box** we are talking about, which you inserted from `Insert>Text>Textbox`, then you are right to declare it as `TextBox`, but it needs to be set like so:

```
Set boxnomecompleto1= cadastro.TextBoxes("Name of your TextBox here")
```

or

```
Set boxnomecompleto1= cadastro.TextBoxes(n) 'where n is your textbox index n=1 for the 1st one n=2 for the 2nd one etc
```

Then you can access it's value like so:

```
listacadastro.Cells(i, 4).Value = boxnomecompleto1.Text
```

**If it's an ActiveX Form Control** we are talking about, which you inserted from `Developer>Insert>ActiveX Controls>Text Box`, then it shouldn't be declared as `TextBox`. Instead it should be declared as `Object` :

```
Dim boxnomecompleto1 As Object
```

Then it needs to be set like so:

```
set boxnomecompleto1 = cadastro.OLEObjects("Name of your TextBox here").Object
```

or

```
set boxnomecompleto1 = cadastro.OLEObjects(n).Object 'where n is your object index n=1 for the 1st one n=2 for the 2nd one etc
```

Then you can access its value like so:

```
listacadastro.Cells(i, 4).Value = boxnomecompleto1.Text
```

Comment: @wNakano Glad I could help. Has your question been answered? Why have you pasted part of my answer in your comment?

Comment: Stravos Jon, thank you for your support. 
I really miss some important pieces of code when i posted here. 

(First)
These variables, varmestre and varservo, are taking the address of workbooks which are contained in "Worksheets("99. Controles").Range("C19").Value" and "Worksheets("99. Controles").Range("C20").Value".
Following as you said, now I declared "varmestre" and "varservo" as strings variables.

This is the way I thought to set workbook full address that can be modified in a easier way. If you know a better way, please show me.

(Second)
I'll do these exchanges with textbox.

Comment: @wNakano Which workbook does the `99. Controles` worksheet belong to? You need to add a reference to that workbook. If you don't, excel will assume you refer to `ActiveWorkbook` which could potentially lead to errors. If the `99. Controles` belongs to the workbook in which your code is written, then you can use `ThisWorkbook` .

Comment: @Stravos Jon, "99. Controles" belongs to ActiveWorkbook, I changed to "ThisWorkbook" and it really worked.
But I can't find a way to Set a worksheet that belongs to the second workbook. For example, I'm using: "Set listacadastro = mestre.Worksheets("01. Lista Cadastro")", since "Set mestre = Workbooks.Open(varmestre)" is used. But it's running an error "Run-time error "9": Subscript out of Range".

Comment: I did everything that you commented. Thank you @Stravos Jon, now the routine is working!

Comment: @wNakano Glad I could help!